# I have issues with terminal service, there appear logins automatically and disappear?

Tags: windows, terminal, service

I have issues with my terminal service manager, there appear logins automatically and and increases the number of users but actually don't enter, my counter goes till 3000 o more in the same day and I just have 15 user.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're saying or what you're asking but I suspeect that you're seeing activity related to attempts to log on to the server using a brute force username/password attack. You can confirm this by watching in TS/RDS manager for multiple listening ports being created and destroyed in quick succession.